# How can I detect CSS classes and ids from HTML and autocomplete using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to switch over from [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) to Visual Studio Code. One thing I really like about Sublime Text is that I have a plugin that will scan all my files and allow me to access my ids and classes within my CSS and SCSS files.

Is there something similar for Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Intellisense for CSS Class Names](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion)

[HTML Class Suggestions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndersEAndersen.html-class-suggestions)

[Class autocomplete for HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AESSoft.aessoft-class-autocomplete)

These extensions provide autocomplete for CSS class names, but neither *appears* to provide support for SCSS files or id's sadly.

[CSS Peek](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek) gives "Go To Definition"/Peek support for classes **and** id's and although it only mentions *.less* support, it seems to support *.scss* files as well!!

I think the latter is what you are looking for.

Comment: Author of [CSS Peek](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek) here. Version 1 of the extension didn't support compiling .scss files and simply tried to parse them as CSS (meaning, you can simply take a valid css file, add the .scss extension, and it would work).

I recently released version 2 of the extension that supports SASS properly. It should now do everything the OP was asking for (in the interests of making the extension behave as close to Brackets as possible)

Comment: `CSS Peek` is awesome. Thanks, @PranayPrakash

Comment: @PranayPrakash any plans to support autocompletion? That would be amazing